# How to change Facebook App Main Icon

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have just created app on `Facebook` to login using Facebook on my Website. Now, I want to change its Main Icon which you can see in below Image. How to do it ?
Do I need to set any extra permissions or setting in `Facebook` app ?
[image: Facebook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the "App details" section and specify a "App Icon" from there.  Although it's in 1024x1024, Facebook will scale it down for you.

[image]

Comment: Depends ... Have you specified valid oauth callback urls?  You need to make your app available to everybody as well, it's a toggle switch at the top under "Status & Review".

Comment: Yes, I have specified valid oauth callback urls. And app is also available for everybody.

Comment: Ok then I guess you are good to go.  At some point, sites where required to specify a Facebook privacy policy URL but that might not be the case anymore.

Comment: I have also set it with terms and conditions, contact us etc. But in json data, I am not getting user name, what to do for that ?

Comment: Username or user's full name?  The full name should always be part of the data returned but not all Facebook accounts have usernames.

Comment: its UserName. I have tried on my account but it is not returning username.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why that is happening.  Perhaps something for a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Click on "App details" and add some so-called Icons.